# Unable to find image 8080:8080 locally

Tags: docker, containers

I am new in docker and created a simple springboot hello world application. I created a dockerfile according to the tutorials and build it by docker.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.1.13-alpine-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} myapp-1.0.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","/myapp-1.0.0.jar"]
```

EDIT: using -p gives another error which is Invalid or corrupt jarfile /myapp-1.0.0.jar

After that I tried to run the docker on my local machine. But I am getting an error which says unable to find image 8080:8080 locally.

```
docker run 8080:8080 --name myhelloimage myuser/myhelloimage:latest
```

I am able to see docker image by `docker images`

```
REPOSITORY                           TAG                         IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myuser/myhelloimage              latest                      c5dfe18b0fb3        14 minutes ago      271MB
```

So what is wrong here why I am getting an error?

Comment: Please take a look into the documentation of the docker cmdline. the ports (8080:8080) should be part of the -p parameter.
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the -p before 8080:8080, so the docker command is interpreting it as an image not a port mapping.  You can see the full documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

Comment: I figured it out later but by using it getting Invalid or corrupt jarfile /myapp-1.0.0.jar error.

Comment: This seems like a separate issue and needs more information, such as your docker build command and if the jar you have built works outside of the container.  (Notably, did you provide the --build-arg parameter when you built the container image?)